# Google Cloud Authentification json keyfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

The following can be found in the manual:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf7N2.png)
Unfortunately, this leads under Windows after the second command to the following error message:
*docker login" requires at most 1 argument.
See 'docker login --help'.
Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]*

can someone help me or does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to replace the HTML entity `&lt;` with `<` and make sure to give the right path of the JSON key-file

Reference: [GCR docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file).

```
set /p PASS=<keyfile.json
docker login -u _json_key -p "%PASS%" https://gcr.io
```